# Database structure when fields are related

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I'm using MYSQL to store data about user orders.  Using PayPal, some orders have only a transaction ID, and others have only a profile ID.  Is it poor database design to have separate fields for txn_id and profile_id, where one or the other is NULL depending on the order?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not poor design at all.

You have a situation where one or the other is `NULL` depending on the context.  The problem arises when you try to enforce that exactly one is `NULL` or at least one is not `NULL`.  To do that effectively, you will need to use a trigger to check the values.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always only one id or the other, you might consider having two fields, one is something like `id_type` and the other is `id_value` (if they are of the same data type).

This might make querying simpler down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options basically:

1. Two fields, one for Transaction and one for Profile
2. One field for both Transaction and Profile and have another field to identify whether is a Transction ID or a Profile ID

I prefer No. 1 (which basically the same as yours) because you maintained the proper naming of the field and not a generic one. And besides you could always use `COALESCE()` or that kind of function to retrieve the not `NULL` one if either is `NULL`.

On that regard it means also that you should have a **artificial primary key** that would not rely on either `Transction ID` or `Profile ID`.